# UI Kitten and initialRouteName

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-native-ui-kitten

I am trying to set a specific tab to start the application. UI kitten's navigation, starts up with the first tab, and actually I want the tab that is in the second position to be the first to appear to the user. I can not find how to set the initialRoute withtin UI kittens Bottom tab bars. I post some of my code so it can be clear:

```
const { Navigator, Screen } = createBottomTabNavigator();

const BottomTabBar = ({ navigation, state }) => (

  <View>
    <Divider />
    <BottomNavigation
      appearance="noIndicator"
      selectedIndex={state.index}
      onSelect={(index) => navigation.navigate(state.routeNames[index])}
    >
      <BottomNavigationTab title="screen1" icon={icon1} />
      <BottomNavigationTab title="screen2" icon={icon2} />

      <BottomNavigationTab title="screen3" icon={icon3} />
    </BottomNavigation>
  </View>
);

export const BottomTabsNavigator = () => (
  <Navigator tabBar={(props) => <BottomTabBar {...props} />}>
    <Screen name="screen1" component={Screen1}/>
    <Screen name="screen2" component={Screen2}/>
    <Screen name="screen3" component={Screen3} />
  </Navigator>
);

export const AppNavigator = () => {

  return (
  <SafeAreaView>
  <NavigationContainer>
    <Navigator headerMode='none' >
      <Screen name={'BottomTabs'} component={BottomTabsNavigator} />
    </Navigator>
  </NavigationContainer>
  </SafeAreaView>
)
};
```

I've tried in multiple positions but it doesn't seem to work.

Answer (score 0):

Within the following component:

```
<Navigator tabBar={(props) => <BottomTabBar {...props} />}>
```

You need to use the following prop: `initialRouteName`, like so:

```
<Navigator initialRouteName={'namehere'} tabBar={(props) => <BottomTabBar {...props} />}>
```

This is telling the navigator what screen to start on when initially rendered! Hope this helps.

For anyone outside of this question that has landed on this page, you can specify what screen you want the navigator to "start" on by using the prop: `initialRouteName`. This then tells the navigator to use this as your landing page!